# Cannot log in after 15.10 Update, cannot use recovery mode

Tags: boot, login, 15.10, recovery-mode

I just upgraded to 15.10 from 14.04, and I cannot login now. I am brought to a command screen asking me to login. Trying `startx` doesn't work. I tried recovery mode and got the following error spammed:

```
intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: failed to disable graphics turbo
```

How should I proceed in attempting to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Normally you cant upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10, you should have gone from 14.04 - 14.10 - 15.04 - 15.10.

Comment: I upgraded with the Software Updater. I have never had a problem before 'skipping' a distribution. Every other time I have updated I have skipped (since 10.04).

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have some conflicting **xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-*** packages installed.

```
dpkg -l xserver-xorg-video-inte* | grep '^ii'
```

I would **apt- get purge** all installed **xserver-xorg-video-intel** packages, and then try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

That should reinstall the newest version of the missing (purged) **xserver-xorg-video-intel** package

Comment: I would just run
"sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel" ?

Comment: Do the 'dpkg -l...' command and "sudo apt-get purge" the installed packages. It's possible that there is only "xserver-xorg-video-intel" installed.

Comment: thank you @minimec


`dpkg -l xserver-xorg-video-inte* | grep '^ii'`

seemed to have no effect

after 

`sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel`

I was able to get into my login page, but it just cycled through and came back to the login again. I will note that the screen suggested it was still 14.04.

The recovery mode was able to run now, when I tried failsafex though it froze. 

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: 'cat /etc/issue' in a Terminal will give you the version of Ubuntu that is installed. If you are really still on 14.04, wait until you will be prompted to upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: Lol I still can't login! I definitely can't see a prompt for an upgrade.

Comment: Do 'cat /etc/issue' in your shell. What version of ubuntu is installed?

Comment: The version is 15.10

Comment: We can continue to debug. For me the next step would be to install the gdm login manager. During installation you will be prompted to choose between gdm and lightdm. Choose gdm. If you are lucky you get an alternate login manager screen, that will maybe allow you to login. -> 'sudo apt-get install gdm'. Let's see what that does...

Comment: Thank you again. I ran the code and got the message:

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Hmm... You really 'borked' your system with your unconventional upgrade procedure. I guess it is not worth, working on it any longer. You would have to 1.) fix your package status, 2.) fix the graphical environment. You probably have a mix of packages and config files. You could pull out the 'package sledgehammer', called **'tasksel'** and remove the complete graphical environment. But that's really only for advanced users! I only recommend that, if you know what you are doing. And again... you would first have to fix the package status, before you could eventually install the tasksel package.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes it sounds like I really did a number on this, and I'm clearly not advanced. Would doing a complete reinstall fix this? I'm desperate at this point, will do anything.

Comment: So reinstall over existing installation is an option on the installation medium ( described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/317501/how-to-make-a-clean-re-install-over-a-same-release-version) ), although I cannot remember having done that myself. I have the /home directory on a separate partition, so I always do a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks, just finished the re-install. Lost chrome, maybe some other stuff, otherwise everything is up in order.

Comment: Take a glass of wine and listen to [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccdDB0qMdZw). Cheers ;)